# Python 2.7: execute sql query

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to execute a sql query to extract one cell from a table.

This is my code below:

```
def gPPT(self, rfId):
    with DBCursor(self.db) as cur:
                cur.execute("SELECT p_p_t " +
                            "FROM q_r_f_d WHERE r_f_i = ?", (rfId))

                pPT = cur.fetchone() 
    return pPT
```

This query will always return one string. When I run my python code I always get the following error message:

```
... an exception of type 'ValueError' occurred
Details:
    parameters are of unsupported type
```

Anyone know where the error is in my code? I tried executing the query directly on my database and it returned exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) specifies that parameters should be a sequence. Note that the parens/brackets do not make the tuple; the comma does. Simply add the comma.

```
        cur.execute("SELECT p_p_t " +
                    "FROM q_r_f_d WHERE r_f_i = ?", (rfId,))
                                                       # ^
```

Comment: hmmmm I notice the other codes that do similar things follow this format, however when I added the missing comma in I got the error: 'TypeError' occurred Details: 'str' object is not callable....

Comment: "FROM q_r_f_d WHERE r_f_i = ?" (rfId,))

Comment: Oh, you're missing a comma between the query string and the parameter. It should be `"FROM q_r_f_d WHERE r_f_i = ?", (rfId,))`.

Comment: Nothing to be embarrassed about: you are not your code. The DB-API can be tricky at first. You'll master it soon enough.